# How to locate the element that has the same class using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am unable to locate the proper element for a BI dashboard pane that has the same class

```
<a class="mi-title" deatta-no-in="inTitleShowed('folder')" daetta-ni-href="" data-ng-bind="navverTreeItemScope.listItem.title" style="" xpath="1">Staging - ALCDE</a>`
```

They all look like the above element and the only thing that change is the dashboard name **Staging - ALCDE**

Comment: Please re-write your question and give proper source code examples

Comment: Please provide your code. SO's rules about minimal examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned *the only thing that change is the dashboard name* i.e. **Staging - ALCDE** so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Staging - ALCDE"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='mi-title' and text()='Staging - ALCDE'][starts-with(@data-ng-bind, 'navverTreeItemScope')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: thanks for your swift help, both codes did not work. I didn't get any error message this time and it did not click on the dashboard. Please, any reason why? Thank you

Comment: @PeaceT What do you mean by **did not click**? Your question and this answer both are for **locating** the element. Do you want to `click()`?

Comment: apologies for not being clear, Yes I want to click on it as well. but when I added click(); to the code, I got a syntax error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElemen

Comment: @PeaceT Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjabB Woohoo its work. Thank you so much you are the best. I am working on a professional project. Please, I will reach out again. Thank you again

Comment: Hi Please, I ran into another problem. I posted it on my page. Please, can you help me look into it? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
WebElement elmt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='mi-title'])[1]"));
```

Change `[1]` to `[2]` etc, this is the number for the element if there is more than one.

Comment: Hi this code did not work it returned an error message xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//*[@class='mi-title'])[1]"}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this xpath for identifying the element

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@data-ng-bind='navverTreeItemScope.listItem.title']"))
```